How can I preserve all audio streams when cutting video files with FFmpeg?
I have a video file of "ts" format, it has two audio tracks, I want to use FFmpeg to cut the file after 10 minutes for 5 minutes and I want to have both audio streams. I used below command, but, the output file has only first audio track.
ffmpeg -i input.ts -ss 00:10:00 -to 00:15:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.ts

What should I do to preserve both audio streams on my output file?

Try adding in -map 0:a

Thanks. It works.

Great news! I have created an answer from this comment....

A small variation is required to your command line to copy all of the audio streams over:
ffmpeg -i input.ts \
-ss 00:10:00 -to 00:15:00 \
-c copy -map 0:a \
output.ts

The addition to your own command line is this: -map 0:a which instructs FFmpeg to stream copy (no encoding or decoding) all of the audio streams into the output container.
Note: I have also simplified your command line somewhat by specifying -c copy which will mean that all codecs involved will be stream copied. In your example this will still only involve the first video stream; if there was more than one video stream which you wished to copy you could then add in -map 0:v to stream copy all video streams.
Resources:

Selecting streams with the -map option All you would ever want to know about the FFmpeg map option.

